# Как отобразить кнопки горизонтально после тега input, который вложен в div блок?

Tags: html, css, css3

Добрый день.

Есть поле для ввода input с классом **string required ctrlenter expanding**, после него следом добавлены две кнопки вверх и вниз. На данный момент эти кнопки отображаются после поля ввода на следующей строке, а необходимо чтобы они шли в ряд в месте с ним. Какие стили необходимо прописать, чтобы это реализовать?

```html
    <div class="poll_item">
      <div class="control-group string required blog_post_poll_poll_items_answer">
        <div class="controls"><input class="string required ctrlenter expanding" display="inline" id="  blog_post_poll_attributes_poll_items_attributes_0_answer" margin="0" name="blog_post[poll_attributes][poll_items_attributes][0][answer]" placeholder="Введите вариант ответа" size="50" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
      <button class="btn btn-bg" display="inline" id="up_id" name="button" type="button">вверх</button>
      <button class="btn btn-bg" display="inline" id="down_id" name="button" type="button">вниз</button>
      <input id="blog_post_poll_attributes_poll_items_attributes_0__destroy" name="blog_post[poll_attributes][poll_items_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="#" class="remove_fields dynamic" data-wrapper-class="poll_item">удалить</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.control-group, button, input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="poll_item">
  <div class="control-group string required blog_post_poll_poll_items_answer">
    <div class="controls"><input class="string required ctrlenter expanding" display="inline" id="  blog_post_poll_attributes_poll_items_attributes_0_answer" margin="0" name="blog_post[poll_attributes][poll_items_attributes][0][answer]" placeholder="Введите вариант ответа"
        size="50" type="text">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-bg" display="inline" id="up_id" name="button" type="button">вверх</button>
  <button class="btn btn-bg" display="inline" id="down_id" name="button" type="button">вниз</button>
  <input id="blog_post_poll_attributes_poll_items_attributes_0__destroy" name="blog_post[poll_attributes][poll_items_attributes][0][_destroy]" type="hidden" value="false"><a href="#" class="remove_fields dynamic" data-wrapper-class="poll_item">удалить</a>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. а что вы изменили?

Comment: @StefanHansch, он добавил `display: inline-block` к элементам

Comment: @StefanHansch добавил стили, в самом верху `.control-group, button, input {  display: inline-block;}` . если ответ вам подходит, пометьте его принятым нажатием галочки напротив ответа слева

Comment: у вас везде стоит display="inline". Или inline  и inline-block одно и тоже?

Comment: это не у меня стоит, а у вас) я html не изменял, только добавил css. про это свойство можно почитать вот тут: [свойство display](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display)

Comment: спасибо, все понял